# Derivative by “definition” using differential

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential, curl

In the section **Cartesian derivation**, in [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) wiki page, they derive and define curl in an different way.

I was always told that a differential is an extremely small change in a variable and that the derivative operator, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$ for instance, is merely a notation to describe how a variable changes as another independent variable changes.

In the article, it is described that the derivative of a function can be denoted as
$$\begin{gather*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x) = \frac{f(x + \mathrm{d}x) - f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}
\end{gather*},$$
which is very similar to
$$\begin{gather*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}
\end{gather*}.$$

When I took ordinary differential equations I was always confused about solving separable DEs with the method of multiplying on both sides by the differentials.

What I really do not understand is if the wikipedia definition is correct. If so, how can I prove it besides thinking intuitively about the differential? When can I treat a differential as a normal variable? Can differentials be added and subtracted from “normal numbers”?

Comment: The reason that notation is used is because of the context. Here the goal is to find formulae for these differential operators in different coordinate systems. And as a representation of a change of coordinates, the Jacobian most naturally manifests itself in the correct spots when differentials are involved. It is a powerful heuristic.

Comment: @NinadMunshi so all that has to do with the Jacobian in the end? Could you elaborate a little more or point me in a direction to understand all that a bit better?

Comment: Alternatively, you can look into Nonstandard analysis for math systems in which they went back to the old notions of having infinitesimals.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonstandard_analysis  The rest of us just use it as a convenient shortcut because it happens to work the same as if it did exist.

Comment: One way to make sense of arguments involving $dx, dy$, etc., is to think of $dx$ and $dy$ as extremely tiny (but finite) numbers and to replace equal signs with approximately equal signs. For example, if $dx$ is a tiny real number then $f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x + dx) - f(x)}{dx}$. At the end of your derivation you will still arrive at the equation that you want, but with approximate rather than exact equality. Then assert that it seems plausible that your equation should hold exactly, because you could make the approximation as close as you like by taking $dx, dy$, etc. sufficiently small.

Comment: @littleO that satisfies my curiosity. Thank you for the amazing idea. I had not thought about that.

Comment: Sure. One more comment -- in undergrad differential equations courses, it is usually not hard to rephrase arguments to avoid multiplying by differentials. For example, if we want to solve the separable ODE $f(y(x)) y'(x) = g(x)$, just notice that the left hand side is the derivative of $F(y(x))$, where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. So take antiderivatives of both sides to obtain $F(y(x)) = G(x) + C$ (where $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$ and $C$ is a constant). Then solve for $y(x)$.

Comment: @littleO so it does not really make sense to multiply by the differential in separable DEs? We do it because it works in the end?

Comment: We can at least say that such arguments are not rigorous (unless perhaps the author has gone to great lengths to make it rigorous by developing the language of differential forms or something like that, but that is rarely done in undergrad ODEs courses). However, the derivations involving $dx, dy$, etc. often can make sense intuitively if you take the viewpoint in my earlier comment. We don't have to throw "infinitesimal intuition" out the window; it's actually very illuminating. But, when I teach ODEs, I prefer to avoid multiplying by differentials entirely.

Comment: @littleO I can not thank you enough for clarifying that for me. I appreciate that a lot! I am graduating in electrical engineering and I do not feel comfortable about the way most engineers treat mathematics. Mainly because I am more of a math person than an engineer.

Comment: Sure! I struggled with these issues a lot myself.